# java: passing argument to copy constructor

Tags: java, copy-constructor

```
Inside of class ATester
{
   private A<Integer> p1,p2;

    p1 = new B<Integer>();
    p2 = new B<Integer>( p1);

}

public class B<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements A<E>
{
     public B()   // default constructor
     {
        // skip
     }

     public B(B other)  // copy constructor
     {
        // skip
     }

}
```

I want to define a copy constructor, which takes another B as argument
but when I pass p1  into

```
p2 = new B<Integer>( p1);
```

when compile, it gives me error message

> "no suitable constructor found for  B< A < Integer > >"

What should I change or add?

Comment: Change `public B(B other)` to `public B(B<E> other)`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik.. It won't help. His reference type of p1, is A<Integer>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

Or call as `p2 = new B<Integer>( (B<Integer>)p1);`

Because what you are trying to do is send `A<Integer>` to `B` in the constructor.
Ultimately it is

```
B b = element of type A<Integer>
```

Which is wrong due to contra-variance of argument type. Either change the argument type in you `B` constructor as per design or do the above mentioned

Comment: THank you very much!  WOuld you please explain little more about  (B<Integer>)p1? what does it mean?

Comment: Ok for example: Animal a = new Dog() is valid. because Dog is also an animal. What you are trying to do is: Dog a = new Animal(). Now dog cant be all animals. Hence it is wrong

Comment: A super type can be used instead of subtype, but not other way around. Above hence, I am type casting p1 from type A to type B<Integer>

Comment: And if I were you, I would change constructor of B to :public B(B<E> other) to avoid compile time warning

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast your `p1` to `B<Integer>` before calling the copy constructor.

```
    p2 = new B<Integer>( (B<Integer>)p1);
```

Or you can define another constructor accepting the Interface type e.g.

```
    public B(A<E> other)  // copy constructor
    {
         //type cast here and use it
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your B already implements A, So change constructor arg from B to A:

```
public class B<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements A<E>
{
     public B()   // default constructor
     {
        // skip
     }

     public B(A other)  // copy constructor
     {
        // skip
     }



}
```

Then you can use both A and B as a valid cons parameter;

```
    A<Integer> p1, p2;
    B<Integer> c = new B<Integer>();

    p1 = new B<Integer>(c);
    p2 = new B<Integer>( p1);
```

Comment: This actually depends on design. I personally wouldn;t do it